# Regex capturing group with exception?

Tags: python, regex

**How to create exceptions for regex capturing groups?**

Suppose I have the following regex, with two capturing groups to detect two uppercase-words between tokens: `"^TOKEN ([A-Z]+) ([A-Z]+) TOKEN$"`.

But suppose also that I don't want matches with the second uppercase-word equal to `"NONE"`, so that `"TOKEN AX BC TOKEN"` match and return `["AX", "BC"]`, but neither `"TOKEN AX NONE TOKEN"` nor `"HELLO AX BC WORLD"` match.

How could I modify the initial regex to achieve this result?

*(If the programming language is relevant, I will be using `Python3.10+`, and `re` module.)*

Comment: Of course the programming language is relevant. That said, just match everything and then just _ignore_ results with `NONE` in them in the code that does something with the result? No need to make that the regex's job.

Comment: That is my current approach @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. Can I do better and filter them directly in the regex search?

Comment: Why would you try to? Are you bottlenecked on this? (aka don't optimize prematurely, and keep your code as readable as possible. Which clever regex work _absolutely_ isn't, regex are the worst gift for future maintainers, including yourself =D)

Comment: If the solution is any difficult to understand, I'll take your advice and keep the code as it is. But in any case, I would like to learn the solution, so that if one day a similar task is a bottleneck in some project of mine, I can apply such a solution, and document it explaining what is being done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prepend a negative lookahead in front of the second token to disqualify `NONE` from being a match:

```
^TOKEN ([A-Z]+) (?!NONE\b)([A-Z]+) TOKEN$
```

To see this Regex applied to your example text, see [this regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/NPwRxs/1)

Explanation:

- `^` from the start of the string
- `TOKEN` match "TOKEN"
- space
- `([A-Z]+)` match and capture any uppercase word
- space
- `(?!NONE\b)` then assert that what follows is not the word `NONE`
- `([A-Z]+)` match any second uppercase word
- space
- `TOKEN` match "TOKEN"
- `$` end of the string